# Spreadsheet for Daily Equipment Hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, logging, tracking

My goal on this is to keep track of equipment hours and have a daily report to reflect total hours and run time.

I want to make a file with 31 days of worksheets in the workbook for the complete month so the files can be organized by date.

The order of the worksheets in the file are as follows:

The first worksheet will be a start summary of the hours for the previous month.

The next 31 worksheets are 1 through 31 for each day of the month

The last worksheet will basically contain the information for the end of the day for the last day of the month in order to copy and paste special values only for the start of the next months start summary. It will be unaffected even if the number of days in the month vary.

I would like the workbook to be set up and ready to use without user manipulation of the formulas involved. All the user would have to do is enter the start hours on the first sheet then every day enter the end of the day total for the various equipment.

**One column example:**

## Sheet 1# --- End of Previous Month Summary Sheet

**Cell Location:** (Sheet 1~~~~Cell A1)

Cell formula: no formula -User entered number for end of the month hours **100**

Finished look:

#### 100

## Sheet 2#--- Day 1

**Cell Location:** (Sheet 2 ~~~~Cell A1)

Cell formula: no formula -User entered number for end of the day hours

Use: Today's Total Hours -value entered at the end of the day by user- **125**

**Cell Location:** (Sheet 2 ~~~~Cell A2)

Cell formula: =+'sheet 1'!A1

Use: Hours from end of previous day - (value pulled from Sheet 1 ~~~~Cell A1- **100**

**Cell Location:** (Sheet 2 ~~~~Cell A3)

Cell formula: =A1-A2

Use: Today's Runtime -simple calculation of the values from cell Sheet 2 ~A1 subtracted from cell Sheet 2~A2 "the above cells"- **24**

Finished look:

#### 124

#### 100

#### 24

*The next day will be set up as follows:*

## Sheet 3#--- Day 2

**Cell Location:** (Sheet 3 , Cell A1)

Cell formula: No formula -User entered number for end of the day hours

Use: Today's Total Hours - (value entered at the end of the day by user- **148**

**Cell Location:** (Sheet 3 , Cell A2)

Cell formula: =+'sheet 2'!A1

Use: Hours from end of previous day- (value pulled from Sheet 2 - Cell A1 - **124**

**Cell Location:** (Sheet 3 - Cell A3)

Cell formula: =A1-A2

Use: Today's Runtime - simple calculation of the values from cell Sheet 3 - A1 minus Sheet 3~A2 "the above cells on the same sheet"-**24**

Finished look:

#### 148

#### 124

#### 24

That was the easy part......

Now to easily make 31 days worth with multiple columns of numbers.

## Sheet 4#,

I right click on the tab, select move or copy, create a copy. Rename the new tab as "sheet 4"

By doing the above method of making a new worksheet, the formulas come out the same as the previous sheet and will pull information from the same (sheet 2) place.

**Cell A1** is user entered number and the number transfers over as the same as the copied sheet.

**Cell A2** is now copied as: =+'sheet 2'!A1

**Cell A3** is copied as the normal "=A1-A2" calculation that is calculated from cells within the same sheet. No problems.

I would like for the formula in **cell A2** to automatically update itself to:

**=+'sheet 3'!A1** when making the next sheet.

How do I get the new sheet to pull the corrected cell formulas without going in and correcting them manually.

With close to 40+ cells of information to be pulled from one sheet and transferred to the next day manually going in and changing this 1240+ times to set up one month would be too much.

Comment: I feel like you put a lot of effort into your question, but it's very difficult to follow. Perhaps you could format it differently or change the wording to reflect the question better.

Comment: If there was a way to put screen shots of what I'm thinking about it would be clearer to what I'm needing this to do. 32 worksheets in a workbook The first worksheet would be data entered by the user to reflect the data of the previous month or "start sheet". The next 31 worksheets are day 1 to day 31 of the month. "Day 1 cell A2" would be the data from the "start sheet cell A2"

Comment: Right now copying and pasting doesn't correct the formulas to pull from the previous sheet. If I copy and paste the result will be day 1 pulling the correct information as I specify, from the start sheet. Day 2 will be pulling information as I specify, from Day 1 cell A2. Day 3 through 31 will be pulling information from Day 1 cell A2. I need them to pull from the day before. 1 from start sheet, day 2 from day 1, day 3 from day 2, day 4 from day 3, 5 from 4, 6 from 5, 7 from 6 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Find and Replace Menu. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-HP001216390.aspx

essentially you want to find in formulas '=+'sheet 3'!A1' and replace to '=+'sheet 4'!A1'. Ive had to make plenty of excel spreadsheets like this before, 2 for a whole year and this was the best solution that I could work with.

Comment: Thanks Jon H. This would take setting up 31 days quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will do what you want, with the assumption that your tab names are controlled and end with ascending numbers as you describe.

I'll break it down for you:

1. Need to know what sheet I'm on, so I know to "calculate" the name of
   the prior day's sheet.  Let's say **XX**= `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)`.  On Sheet 1, this returns the string "Sheet 1", on Sheet 2, it returns "Sheet 2"
2. Now, I need to parse this string to figure out the number, and subtract 1 from it to get yesterdays number, but only if I'm not day 1. **YY** = `=IF(MID(XX,7,2)>1,MID(XX,7,2)-1,1)`
3. Lastly, and here's the magic, use the `INDIRECT` function to calculate my "target" on the fly.  `=INDIRECT("'Sheet "& YY &"'!A1")`

Put it all together, with the parts you have to customize in bold/italics  (I did not use code markup, as highlighting doesn't seem to work inside of CODE):

=INDIRECT("***'Sheet*** "& IF(MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256),***7***,2)>1,MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256),***7***,2)-1,1) &"'!***A1***")

What has to be updated:

- 'Sheet ' -- replace with your sheet prefix (the part before the
  number)
- '7' -- replace with length of your above prefix +1 (or substitute with a function)
- 'A1' -- replace with the cell address of what you want from the previous sheet
- Don't change "filename" -- it has to stay as that (special reserved name)
- Don't have to change the A1 inside the CELL function.  It is arbitrary and not really needed for this reserved name and doesn't have to change.

Comment: How do I apply this? Do I add this as part of the formula in the cell and replace the words sheet and file name with just that.  Sorry for my lack of knowledge

Comment: I added some more clarity on this I hope.  Note, I wrote it assuming you only needed this formula once.  If you need it several times per page, then I would break it into 2 formulas-- one to figure out the prior sheet name, and one with the INDIRECT part only.